# junos 802.1ad on EX and MX

Tags: juniper, fortigate, 802.1ad

given following szenario:

I have a Juniper MX204 Service router, a FGT200F Cluster is connected via a EX4400 Switch Stack.

```
------------     ----------     ---------
| FGT-200F | --- | EX4400 | --- | MX204 |
------------     ----------     ---------
```

due to the need for several (>100) VLANs beetween the MX204 and the FGT my plan was to use QinQ VLAN Stacking between the Fortigate and the MX so that there is no Configuration necessary on the EX4400 Stack.

We had to learn that hardware acceleration on the FGT-200 is not supported on double -stacked VLANs on the FGT. The Fortigate TAC told us that Hardware acceleration is only working fine when configuring 802.1AD VLANs with TPID 0x88a8.

As a Workaround we disabled Hardware acceleration on the FGT which works fine until now.

To gain more performance we followed the advice of Fortinet TAC and changed the Setup to 802.1AD .
We are utilizing a lot of Links with VLAN Stacking, but there was no need to implement 802.1AD until now. So there is no "well known working" configuration available.

The Outer VLAN was configured on the EX4400 with TPID 0x88a8

```
vlans {
    VL1002 {
        vlan-tags outer 0x88A8.1002;
    }
}
xe-0/0/44 {
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            interface-mode trunk;
            vlan {
                members VL1002;
            }
            storm-control default;
        }
    }
}
```

on the MX we terminated the Double tagged VLANs, we had to add the "tag-protocol-id" values in the "gigether-options" otherwise it was not possible to commit the configuration.

```
interfaces {
    xe-0/1/1 {
        hierarchical-scheduler;
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services;
        gigether-options {
            ethernet-switch-profile {
                tag-protocol-id [ 0x8100 0x88a8 ];
            }
        }
        unit 12210 {
            vlan-tags outer 0x88A8.1002 inner 0x8100.210;
            family inet {
                address XXXX;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion the MX should snd double Tagged Frames with 0x88A8.1002 als outer and 0x8100.210 as inner tags. The MX should match the 0x88A8.1002 as outer tag and handle all communication within VLAN named "VL1002".

a "show int" on the MX shows:

```
Flags: Up SNMP-Traps 0x4000 VLAN-Tag [ 0x88a8.1002 0x8100.210 ]  Encapsulation: ENET2
```

the EXes are learing MAC addresses on both sides.

Can anybody confirm this?

Unfortunately this setup is not working, we don't have any possibility to capture Traffic on a Mirror port or a Tap device so i have to rely on the Tools that are implemented in the Devices itself.

i pulled a traffic capture on the Fortigate, investigating the PCAP with Wireshark it tells me that the first Tag 1002 is prepended by TPID 0x8100, not 0x88a8 as configured. Therefor no communication is possible. Any ideas what could cause this and how i could solve it?

A "diag sniffer packet" on the FGT shows that ARPs from the MX are beeing received on the Physical X1 interface, but neither the Interface representing the Outer 802.1AD VLAN nor the interface Representing the inner 802.1Q VLAN is matching any traffic.

So i think that the Error must be somewhere on the Juniper side.

Are there any ideas what can cause this problem?

Comment: The inner C-tag should always be 0x8100 and the outer S-tag 0x88a8. Double tagging with 0x8100 is very sensitive to even slight misconfiguration.